# Segmented control in action sheet IOS

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet, custom-view, uialertcontroller

I am trying to add segmented control in the actionsheet  the same way apple's maps application has used.[image]

I found a way to add as a subview in actionsheet's view but this is not recommended by apple.I found following comment somewhere.

> You might want to be careful with this. Apple may not like it. From the documentation: "UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:." –  Eric Goldberg Mar 4 '14 at 2:28

can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to figure this out for ages too. The clue was in the bottom left - the lines do not go all they way to the left edge. It is actually a UITableView and the gaps between the rows are actually blank section headers with custom sizes.

I haven't fully implemented it yet but the important bits are:

1. In storyboard make a new UIViewController.
2. In the ViewController attributes selector  set `Presentation` to `Over Current Context`
3. In the View, change `Background` to `Clear Color`
4. Add a UITableView. Set up the left, bottom and right constraints. Set the height of the TableView so it only covers the bottom half of the View
5. Change the `Style` to `Grouped`
6. Implement the delegates as for normal prototype based TableView
7. Create a segue to the ViewController from the action button and set the `Segue` to `Present Modally`

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a `UIActionSheet` at all. That is a `UIViewController` presenting using a custom 1UIPresentationController1 and `transitionDelegate`. Its easy to tell because it takes over the bar and doesn't have the same style as a `UIActionSheet`.

You can simply create your own viewController to manage the view you'd like, then present it using the new Custom Transition API from iOS7.

Here are some resources to help get you started.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LookInside/Introduction/Intro.html
>
> http://www.raywenderlich.com/96062/custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-swift
>
> http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/